# Rust Struct Type Mismatch using closures

Tags: data-structures, rust

I need to use a closure because of the callback method but I haven't used them before so this level of debugging is beyond my current skill.

This library is so I can feed data into a pipeline linked list and have it "shuffle" along each of the links, and be destroyed after the final callback returns.

Obviously its a type mismatch but what is the rust-ian way of dealing with this?

```
mod DataPipeline
{
    struct Callback<CB>
    where CB: FnMut(),
    {
        callback: CB,
        priority: u8
    }


    enum _Data <T: Copy>
    {
        None,
        _Data {item: T, next: Box<_Data<T>>} //Linked list
    }


    struct DataPipeline<T: Copy, CB: FnMut()>
    {
        curr: isize, //Pointer to the current element
        rear: _Data<T>, //Pointer to the last added element
        CBL: Vec<Callback<CB>>, //Vector of functions to call back when data is available
    }

    impl<T, CB> DataPipeline<T, CB> 
    where T: Copy, CB: FnMut(),
    {
        fn new(&mut self)
        {
            DataPipeline::<T, CB>
            {
                curr: 0,
                rear: _Data::None,
                CBL: Vec::new()  //See if adding default Callback(_destroy(), 1) works somehow
            };
            unsafe{let destructor = Callback{callback: || self._destroy(), priority: 1};
            self.CBL.push(&destructor);}
        }
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:40:27
   |
39 |             unsafe{let destructor = Callback{callback: || self._destroy(), priority: 1};   
   |                                                        ------------------ the found closure
40 |             self.CBL.push(&destructor);}
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Callback`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected struct 'Callback<CB>'
           found reference '&Callback<[closure@src\main.rs:39:56: 39:74]>'
```

Comment: The immediate type error arises because the `CBL` vector contains elements of type `Callback`, but you're trying to push onto it a `&Callback`—changing `.push(&destructor)` to `.push(destructor)` will instead move the `destructor` into the vector rather than attempting to push a borrow of it.  That's pretty basic Rust ownership/borrowing stuff, nothing at all to do with closures.  However, a `Vec<Callback<CB>>` accommodates `Callback`s with one specific `CB` and since every closure has its own type, the vector will only be able to hold instances of one closure; consider trait objects instead.

Comment: @eggyal I followed your advice and did it with trait objects, and built a register function almost exactly like the one in the By Example and Docs for `std::ops::Fn()`  callbacks using the `dyn` keyword, however it now complains it can't figure out the size at compile time, could you possibly elaborate on your answer here in an actual answer please? That way I can accept it if it works and give you the recognition you deserve.

Comment: Since they're unsized, trait objects (currently) require indirection: that is, the type of `Callback.callback` needs to be something like `Box<dyn FnMut()>`.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] - the smallest program that still produces the compilation error you did not expect.

Comment: @andrey it already is the MRE. Not sure how much more lean I can make it

Comment: Does the error go away if you get rid of `priority`, `curr`, `rear`, `_Data` (as in remove them and all references to them)? Have you tried an empty closure instead of self.destroy()?